# Regex - Capture only if a set of words exist

Tags: regex

For example:

```
"Washroom L20 is broken"
"LAV #L20 needs to be fixed"
"R20 lavatory is broken"
"Lav issue - check L20"
```

I want to check if `Washroom`, `Lavatory`, `Lav` are present in the sentence before capturing `L20` or `R20` only. Is there any suggestions?

I am able to capture the first two but struggling throughout the rest.

What I tried:

```
(?:(?:(?:LAV?)|(?:LAVATORY?)|(?:WASHROOM?))(?:\s*?))(?:(?:['#@:+-]?\s?)(\b[LR]\d{1,2}\b))
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Use this https://regexr.com/ to check and visualize your regex real-time. It’s being helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if your engine supports look behind assertions.
If it does, this should work:

Using whitespace boundary
`(?im)^(?=.*(?:lav|washroom)).*(?<!\S)['#@:+-]?[^\S\r\n]?([lr]\d{1,2})(?!\S)`

https://regex101.com/r/UeMUfX/3

Formatted

```
 (?im)      
 ^ 
 (?=
      .* 
      (?: lav | washroom )
 )
 .* 
 (?<! \S )
 ['#@:+-]? [^\S\r\n]? 
 ( [lr] \d{1,2} )              # (1)
 (?! \S )
```

Using word boundary
`(?im)^(?=.*(?:lav|washroom)).*['#@:+-]?[^\S\r\n]?\b([lr]\d{1,2})\b`

https://regex101.com/r/UeMUfX/2

Formatted

```
 (?im)
 ^
 (?=
      .* 
      (?: lav | washroom )
 )
 .*
 ['#@:+-]? [^\S\r\n]?
 \b
 ( [lr] \d{1,2} )              # (1)
 \b
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to do it without look(behinds/aheads):

```
(?:washroom|lav(?:atory)?).*?([lr]20)|([lr]20).*?(?:washroom|lav(?:atory)?)
```

Uses the PHP regex, so may be some differences depending on your engine.
It basically looks for either the two components in either order, with any characters between them.

[Regex in Action](https://regex101.com/r/hSfFwI/3)